# SMS for different order events in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, orders

I want to send SMS to customers when ever an order status changes from *pending > processing > complete* (for all sort of changes).

For *pending* process(when place order is clicked), i should able to get a SMS. Below is the code: `Onserver.php`

```
public function sendSMS ($observer)
    {
        $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
        foreach($orderIds as $orderId)
        {
            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
            $orderId = $order->getId();
            $order_status = $order->getStatus();
            $smsMessageTemp =Mage::getModel('core/variable')->loadByCode('template_sms_order_placement_confirmation')->getValue('plain');
                . . . . .
         }
 }
```

When admin changes the state from *pending* to *processing* , how to send sms for different events.

In my .xml file:

```
     <events> 
        <sales_order_save_after>
            <observers>
                <Metro_SellerPurchaseOrder>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>sellerpurchaseorder/observer</class>
                   <method>sendSMS</method>
                </Metro_SellerPurchaseOrder>
           </observers>
        </sales_order_save_after>
    </events>
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Why don't you look for readymade solution
https://magecomp.com/magento-sms-notification.html

Answer (score 4):

First you need to track order status changes,

Magento is provide to  `track old data and new  changed data` using   `getOrigData()`  and `getData()` on save event fire.So easily using the feature,you can get `changes Status and on basic of this,you can fire the  Sms`

### Error:

When **sales_order_save_after** event is `fire` then you can get `only one order data` that means code at observer is **wrong**.

### Solution:

As i said that when Model is saving then you can  get old and new Data using

**Current Data:** `$Object->getOrigData();`

and

**Changing  new Data :** `$object->getData()`

Using those function when  you can easy track `order status changes`.

And suggesting to you that use event **sales_order_save_commit_after**  instead  of   `sales_order_save_after` because if any **issue has occurred during the save magento is roll back to  old data**  and show **the errors**.

you can Old status by       `$OldStatus=$order->getOrigData('status'`)

**and new Status**

```
$NewStatus=$order->getData('status');
```

### Code:

```
  public  function sendSMS($observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

        if (!$order->getId()) {
            //order not saved in the database
            return $this;
        }

        /* @var $order Mage_Sales_Model_Order */

        $OldData=$order->getOrigData();
        $NewData=$order->getData();
        $OldState==$order->getOrigData('state');
        $NewState=$order->getState();
        $OldStatus=$order->getOrigData('status');
        $NewStatus=$order->getStatus();


        /* Fire sms when New Status  and  old Statu are not same */
        if($OldStatus!=$NewStatus){
            //fire sms;
            $smsMessageTemp =Mage::getModel('core/variable')->loadByCode('template_sms_order_placement_confirmation')->getValue('plain');
        }



        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: why down vote??

Comment: sr_magento ,i am agree with you

Comment: maybe because you are reinventing bicycle again and again???  http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?q=SMS&pl=0   take one of these extensions and use it, or see how its built and do your own...

Comment: @SR_Magento, Amit. I am agree with you both. because some people dont like answers, then they are downvoting. but if they give the explanation, that should helps to someone.

Answer (score 0):

Tracking order status code and applying sms api on each event is little difficult.

Its easy to use **"extension" available free** for magento like "Spring Edge Magento sms extension" which is Compatible with: Magento versions 1.x and 2.x

Magento sms module events configuration :

- Send sms to customer and admin on new order is placed.
- When order status is set to hold.
- When order status is set to Unhold.
- When order is cancelled.
- When order status is set Shipment.

http://springedge.com/magento-sms-extension-module-free.html